What are the unit group and the divisors of zero of the set of smooth real-valued functions $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?
I know that $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a ring under function addition and function multiplication.
The group of units are all functions $1/f$, where $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is not zero. Is there a way to write this more formally? Is this correct?
Also, I have no idea on how to find the zero divisors of this ring. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance! :)

Welcome to MSE! Here's a few hints:
First, for the group of units. It's "obvious" that if $f(x) = 0$ at some point, then $f^{-1}$ cannot be smooth. Can you show that if $f$ is nowhere vanishing then $f^{-1}$ is smooth? That is, can you show that the units are exactly the nowhere vanishing functions. As a further hint, how might you compute the derivative (and the iterated derivatives) of $f^{-1}$ in this case?
Second, for the zero divisors. Say that $f \equiv 0$ on some interval $(a,b)$. That is, $f(x) = 0$ whenever $a < x < b$. In this case, do you see why $f$ must be a zero divisor? As a hint, can you find a nonzero function $g$ whose support is entirely inside $(a,b)$? Do you see why that ensures $fg \equiv 0$? Conversely say that $f$ is a zero divisor with $fg \equiv 0$. Then since $g$ is not identically $0$, we must have $g(x) \neq 0$ for some point $x$. Then $g \neq 0$ on some neighborhood of $x$ (do you see why?) so that $f \equiv 0$ on this whole neighborhood. That is, the zero divisors are exactly the functions vanishing on some interval!

I hope this helps ^_^

What do you mean by $f^{-1}$? Do you mean $1/f$? If so, the function is not even defined at $x$ where $f(x) = 0$, let alone smooth.

Yes, I mean $1/f$. As you said, it's in particular not smooth, and as I said this is "obvious" for exactly this reason.

It isn't very important, I just don't think it makes sense to discuss smoothness at a point not in the domain of the function.
